# How to use global gitignore with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a global gitignore file defined in my gitconfig but Visual Studio Code seems to not be interpreting it. How would I use a global gitignore with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: have a look here: https://anthonygharvey.com/productivity/how_to_create_a_global_gitignore_file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT:** Comment from Piyush Soni.

As of 9 august 2021, for this configuration to work, you also have to check `useIgnoreFiles`, hence:

```json
"search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles": true,
"search.useIgnoreFiles": true
```

---

You have to add these in your settings to allow global gitignore:

```json
"search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles": true
```

<sub>Found on [Microsoft/vscode#59364](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59364).</sub>

For this to work, I also had to restart my VSCode session.

---

Note that you must already **have a global ignore file** if you want it to be useful. You can set or see which one is set with the next commands:

```sh
# get
git config --global core.excludesFile
# set
git config --global core.excludesFile <filename>
```

See more details about gitignore [on the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: that one is not effective in my case

Comment: @PlagTag could you elaborate by telling us which version you are using and issues you are encontering and maybe I would be able to help you?

Comment: That is a version on which this is implemented... Is your global ignore file well configured ? `git config --global core.excludesfile` should return its path.

Comment: Yes that works. But it just worked after doing: git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global

Comment: @PlagTag I've added the related information. Glad it could help :)

Comment: This did not work for me (v1.56.2). I wonder if this is a regression because the files were being ignored before.

Comment: Anyone who's reading the answer, please note, as of now (9 Aug 2021), the 'Use global ignore files' option works ONLY when you also click the 'Use ignore files'. This is not what I was expecting actually - I thought I could only ignore the files mentioned in the global one and "not ignore" the ones in the local .gitignore file to the repository.

Comment: @PiyushSoni not sure this has not been the case all along, anyway, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Doesn't work if core.excludesFiles is set inside an include of ~/.gitconfig, it needs to be inside ~/.gitconfig itself.

Answer (score 9):

This steps to Windows:

1. Open GitBash Terminal
2. Run `touch ~/.gitignore_global` to create a global .gitignore file in the home directory
3. Edit file in your home directory: ~/.gitignore_global
4. Add `.vscode/` and any other files or directories that you want to ignore and not include in project-specific .gitignore files;
5. Save file;
6. In GitBash run `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

Done!
That’s it! Using .gitignore_global will let you customize your editor without having to edit and commit changes to the .gitignore file for every single project.

Comment: also works on my Mac. :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is several months old but the correct answer for this, ***today***, is to open settings in Code and search for "*git*" and then check the box "*Use Global Ignore Files*".

Of course, you can add it manually too, but no need for that now as it has been added in settings.

Comment: Just a note: I still had to restart VS Code (as mentioned in the currently accepted answer) to see a visual update in the explorer

Comment: I still prefer the json way of editing settings, especially when you want to share some, it is much easier to just copy paste IMHO

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.75 (Jan 2023) will add documentation to the `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` setting, through [PR 169688](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/169688) (for [issue 168129](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168129))

> Ripgrep (used by VSCode) seems to just [use the global gitignore as the global ignore](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/61101289fabc032fd8e90009c41d0b78e6dfc9a2/doc/rg.1.txt.tpl#LL154C29-L154C29).

That setting now says:

> `useGlobalIgnoreFiles`: Controls whether to use your global gitignore file (e.g., from `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`) when searching for files.
> Requires `search.useIgnoreFiles` to be enabled.

This is available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

---

As noted by [Yann Duran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281489/yann-duran) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333484/how-to-use-global-gitignore-with-visual-studio-code/74881233?noredirect=1#comment135191965_74881233), even when `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` is set to true, the `git config --get core.excludesFile`, if it has been set, will be used by VSCode.

Comment: I just found this answer on 2023-07-14, but in version 1.80.0 on Windows 10.0.19045 (22H2) it's not working for me. git config --get core.excludesFile confirms that it's set to the correct path of the file that I'm editing. Both search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles & search.useIgnoreFiles are set to true. And I've restarted VSCode.

Comment: @YannDuran Did you set in VSCode settings `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` to false? And `search.useIgnoreFiles` to true?

Comment: yes, I'd just edited my comment before I saw your question. Why would I set search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles to false?

Comment: @YannDuran I suspect that if `git config --get core.excludesFile` is set, that path will take precedence over the `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` global gitignore one, even when you set `search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles` to true.

Comment: Thanks for your help! core.excludesFile is set to /var/services/homes/myusername/.config/git/ignore which is the file that I've put my global values.

Comment: @YannDuran Sure thing. I have included your comment in the answer for more visiblilty. Can you confirm I did understand correctly the situation?

Comment: aren't search.useGlobalIgnoreFiles & search.useIgnoreFiles two separate things? One for using local ignore vales & the other for using global ignore values? I got the impression from your answer & the description for the settings that both had to be set to true for global values to be used. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254481/discussion-between-vonc-and-yann-duran).

Answer (score -2):

This was an issue on my end, I had to full reference my ignore file in my config for Windows.

Comment: What do you mean, "full reference"? Can you share what you had to do?

Comment: @drkvogel I don't know if you ran into the same problem as weel, but for me the fix was a little bit of vscode config. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975032/6320039) :)

Answer (score -6):

To ignore vscode globally you can use this in `.gitignore` file:

```
**/.vscode
```

This ignores `vscode` in all subdirectorys